# Excel: Add sequential column using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sequence

I am trying to add a column in Excel using VBA for sequential numbers.

```
Column 1    Column 2
            Xyz Data
            Zyx Data
            Yzx Data
```

I wish to add a numbered sequence to column 1.

```
Column 1    Column 2
1           Xyz Data
2           Zyx Data
3           Yzx Data
```

Also I would like to control where the sequence starts from. For example from 5 onwards....

```
Column 1    Column 2
5           Xyz Data
6           Zyx Data
7           Yzx Data
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use vba, enter 1, 2 then select 1,2, hover mouse to selections lower right corner until you see + sign, click and drag down.

Comment: Hi Jules. I am aware I do not need to use VBA, however, I am working on a macro to manipulate a spreadsheet to suit, and am new to VBA. Due to the nature of the work, I will have to add sequential numbers in VBA so any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on Row 1 to 100 of column A, you could try this:

```
Dim startNum As Long
Dim offNum As Long
Dim i As Long

Let startNum = InputBox("Start from:")
Let offNum = startNum - 1
For i = 1 To 100
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Row(R" & i & "C1) + " & offNum
Next
```

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks this seems to work well for  me. I replace i = 1 To 100 with i = 1 To LastRow where LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, allows us to use it for any number of rows

Comment: Sure, both the "1" and "100" can be replaced by variables. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub enumeration()

Dim j, k As Integer
'determine the number to start with
j = Application.InputBox("What number should I start with?")
'determine how many rows are there to enumerate
k = Cells(1, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = 0 To k - 2
    Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = i + j
Next i

End Sub
```